# Laravel - How to loop inside loop with two table but not join table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I know this is a stupid question, but I hope there's someone who have a kindness and want to share their knowledge and help my problems.

I have a table like this

(items table)

```
+---------+-------+-------+-----------+
| item_id | stock | price | name      |
+---------+-------+-------+-----------+
| 1       | 10    | 9.4   | Paper     |
+---------+-------+-------+-----------+
| 2       | 10    | 12.8  | Pencil    |
+---------+-------+-------+-----------+
| 3       | 10    | 99.9  | Note Book |
+---------+-------+-------+-----------+
| 4       | 10    | 4.5   | Pen       |
+---------+-------+-------+-----------+
```

then I have another table like this

(purchase request details table)

```
+---------------+-------+---------+-----+
| pr_details_id | pr_id | item_id | qty |
+---------------+-------+---------+-----+
| 1             | 1     | 1       | 1   |
+---------------+-------+---------+-----+
| 2             | 1     | 2       | 2   |
+---------------+-------+---------+-----+
| 3             | 1     | 3       | 1   |
+---------------+-------+---------+-----+
| 4             | 2     | 3       | 1   |
+---------------+-------+---------+-----+
```

And then I wanna looping the table items and insert pr_qty and subtotal inside items table, something like this

-- PR No.1

```
+---------+-------+-----------+-----+----------+
| item_id | price | name      | qty | subtotal |
+---------+-------+-----------+-----+----------+
| 1       | 9.4   | Paper     | 1   | 9.4      |
+---------+-------+-----------+-----+----------+
| 2       | 12.8  | Pencil    | 2   | 25.6     |
+---------+-------+-----------+-----+----------+
| 3       | 99.9  | Note Book | 1   | 99.9     |
+---------+-------+-----------+-----+----------+
| 4       | 4.5   | Pen       | 0   | 0        |
+---------+-------+-----------+-----+----------+
```

--PR No.2

```
+---------+-------+-----------+-----+----------+
| item_id | price | name      | qty | subtotal |
+---------+-------+-----------+-----+----------+
| 1       | 9.4   | Paper     | 0   | 0        |
+---------+-------+-----------+-----+----------+
| 2       | 12.8  | Pencil    | 0   | 0        |
+---------+-------+-----------+-----+----------+
| 3       | 99.9  | Note Book | 1   | 99.9     |
+---------+-------+-----------+-----+----------+
| 4       | 4.5   | Pen       | 0   | 0        |
+---------+-------+-----------+-----+----------+
```

I have no idea how to create this, anyone please help me, sorry for bad English, and thanks for answer
If you don't mind, please give me a script for Laravel :)

Answer (score 0):

Use laravel's orm to search through tables. But i think if u want to product exactly like that.
You're gonna use sql joins.
 DB::select('select i.id,i.name,i.price from items i left join purchase_details pr on i.id = pr.item_id');

Or you need to read about laravel's eloquent to go through tables.

Answer (score 0):

Easy query ! it would be something like this (just follow the idea syntax maybe not accurate because the case here is not clear)

```
Update purchase_table SET subtotal=pur.qty*itm.price
FROM purchase_table pur INNER JOIN items itm ON itm.item_id=pur.item_id
```